# How to improve Casting Object performance toList on c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am converting to rows to column using below function, however i can pivot only 4 rows in 1 second. This is too slow for my application

```
 public static DataTable ToPivotTable<T, TColumn, TRow, TData>(
this IEnumerable<T> source,
Func<T, TColumn> columnSelector,
Expression<Func<T, TRow>> rowSelector,
Func<IEnumerable<T>, TData> dataSelector)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        var rowName = ((MemberExpression)rowSelector.Body).Member.Name;
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(rowName.ToString(), typeof(DateTime)));
        var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct();



foreach (var column in columns)
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.ToString(), typeof(double)));

    var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                     .Select(rowGroup => new
                     {
                         Key = rowGroup.Key,
                         Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                             rowGroup,
                             c => c,
                             r => columnSelector(r),
                             (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                     });

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var dataRow = table.NewRow();
        var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
        items.Insert(0, row.Key);
        dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
        table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return table;
}
```

I realized that following lines taking 250ms to finish for each row. This is the main problem.

```
var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

How can I improve performance for that line?

Comment: Nice function. Much more generic than the one I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code seems too generic to me:

```
Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                         rowGroup,
                         c => c,
                         r => columnSelector(r),
                         (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
```

`columns` is (effectively) a distinct `IEnumerable<string>` which you are computing for each `rowGroup` - you should pre-compute it in the most helpful form (but a `ToList` wouldn't be a bad start).

Using `GroupJoin` to select the `dataSelector` occurrence of each possible `columnSelector(r)` value seems like overkill.

What if you did

```
var columns = source.Select(columnSelector).Distinct().Orderby(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Forcing an explicit (alphabetical) order on the `ItemArray`.

Then you can do

```
Values = rowGroup.GroupBy(r => columnSelector(r))
                 .Orderby(rg => rg.Key)
                 .Select(rg => dataSelector(rg))
```

Along with @MatthewWatson's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This code is inefficient:

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var dataRow = table.NewRow();
    var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
    items.Insert(0, row.Key);
    dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
    table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

You are creating a list (an O(N) operation), then inserting an item at the start of it (another O(N) operation) and then later turning it into an array (yet another O(N) operation).

You could improve this as follows:

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var dataRow = table.NewRow();
    var items   = row.Values.Cast<object>();
    items = new[] {row.Key}.Concat(items);
    dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();
    table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

This means that there is only one O(N) operation - the call to `items.ToArray()`.

(Without being able to compile that, I don't know if that is exactly right - you might need `items = new object[] {row.Key}.Concat(items);`.)

Comment: Thank you, however now 'dataRow.ItemArray = items.ToArray();' this line took 250ms.

Comment: @S.Doe Do you even need to cast it to `object`?  How long does it take if you omit the `.Cast<object>`? If it still takes ~250ms then there's little you can do. (So if you time `row.Values.ToArray()`, how long does that take?). Also, how are you timing it?

Comment: I suspect he time will be taken by the Linq to create each element of the `rows` sequence. It's doing a `GroupJoin()` for each element.

Comment: Only What i want is converting rows to columns. I don't know if i need casting to object or not. It is possible using without object? I am using debug line by line and it shows the response time about timing from the previous line.

Comment: @S.Doe I don't think it's the cast now, I think it's the GroupJoin() being done for each row.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the logic for groupjoin()?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know what that code is doing, so I can't really comment.

Comment: That part of the code simply select the datatable by primary key. which makes transposed datatable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var items = row.Values.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

You may think the Cast() is causing the delay; however, the actual running task is the ToList() which actually start to enumerate through row.Values.

So your question should be how to improve this code

```
var rows = source.GroupBy(rowSelector.Compile())
                 .Select(rowGroup => new
                 {
                     Key = rowGroup.Key,
                     Values = columns.GroupJoin(
                         rowGroup,
                         c => c,
                         r => columnSelector(r),
                         (c, columnGroup) => dataSelector(columnGroup))
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: But then, how  should i change the following part which starts with foreach loop; foreach (var row in rows)
    {